# How to use ffmpeg for video to image and vice-versa conversion?

Tags: c#, c, ffmpeg

How can I use ffmpeg functions to decode video to images and then again encode the images to video?

Can I write a program for this instead of using CLI?

Ideally I would like to use ffmpeg dll and reference required functions from my c# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg to extract images from videos and in reverse generate video back from sequence of images.

Either you can use ffmpeg wrapper e.g http://www.mediasoftpro.com/post/18/extracting-frames-from-video-and-re-encoding-image.aspx or can use c# "Process() class to execute ffmpeg commands in background with c# application.